# change setter value in style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I'm programming in WPF(c#). I'm trying to change value in a setter of style.

my style is:

```
<Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="st">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
</Style>
```

and I use it in a button:

```
<Button x:Name="btnCancel" Style="{StaticResource st}" Content="انصراف" Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="18" Width="139" Height="53" FontFamily="2  badr" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Click="btnCancel_Click_1" />
```

and what I try to do is this code:

```
Style style = new Style();
style = (Style) Resources["st"];
Setter setter =(Setter) style.Setters[1];
setter.Value = 30;
```

after setting font size to `30` I get this error?

**After a “SetterCollectionBase” is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified**

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using the style somewhere? Show more code. This is working if given that I just use what you have.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing pure UI and behind the code while some answers recommend you to use MVVM which will really make a lot of things easier.

Why do you need to manipulate the Style? Is it just for the button and you want to manipulate its FontSize? I assume you are doing this on the Click event of the button where it changes the fontsize.

Try this then

```
 private void btnCancel_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null) button.FontSize = 30;
    }
```

Comment: Agreed, UI-specific (not data-related and non business-logic-related concerns) are OK in code behind.

Answer (score 9):

The styles can be set only once (**sealed after compiling**), you can't change it with code

so the solutions are

1. create a style by code

   ```
       Style st = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Control));
       st.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Tahoma")));
       st.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.FontSizeProperty, 14.0));
   ```

later you can change it

```
        st.Setters.OfType<Setter>().FirstOrDefault(X => X.Property == Control.FontSizeProperty).Value = 30.0;//safer than Setters[1]
```

or

1. change the property directly

   ```
   btnCancel.FontSize=30.0;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a view model, something like this (I'm using the MVVM Lite class ViewModelBase, you just need something that supports property change notification):

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private double _FontSize = 0.0;
    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return this._FontSize; }
        set { this._FontSize = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.FontSize); }
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of it in your window along with a getter:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public MyViewModel MyViewModel {get; set;}
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MyViewModel = new MyViewModel { FontSize = 80 };
    }
}
```

And then finally you need to bind your style to use the value in the view model:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="st">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}, Path=MyViewModel.FontSize}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```